# Submenu on left side does not appear when add javascript for right menu. But why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this menu here. It works fine. I want one on the left side of the page and one on the right. When I have only the left menu it works perfectly. But as soon as I add the javascript code for the right menu something seems to affect the js of the left one and the submenues don't appear anymore.

Could someone please help me?

Thank you very much

```js
/*navmenu-left*/

var mcVM_options = {
  menuId: "menu-v",
  alignWithMainMenu: false
};
/* www.menucool.com/vertical/vertical-menu.*/
init_v_menu(mcVM_options);

function init_v_menu(a) {
  if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    start_v_menu(a)
  }, false);
  else window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload", function() {
    start_v_menu(a)
  })
}

function start_v_menu(i) {
  var e = document.getElementById(i.menuId),
    j = e.offsetHeight,
    b = e.getElementsByTagName("ul"),
    g = /msie|MSIE 6/.test(navigator.userAgent);
  if (g)
    for (var h = e.getElementsByTagName("li"), a = 0, l = h.length; a < l; a++) {
      h[a].onmouseover = function() {
        this.className = "onhover"
      };
      h[a].onmouseout = function() {
        this.className = ""
      }
    }
  for (var k = function(a, b) {
      if (a.id == i.menuId) return b;
      else {
        b += a.offsetTop;
        return k(a.parentNode.parentNode, b)
      }
    }, a = 0; a < b.length; a++) {
    var c = b[a].parentNode;
    c.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className += " arrow";
    b[a].style.left = c.offsetWidth + "px";
    b[a].style.top = c.offsetTop + "px";
    if (i.alignWithMainMenu) {
      var d = k(c.parentNode, 0);
      if (b[a].offsetTop + b[a].offsetHeight + d > j) {
        var f;
        if (b[a].offsetHeight > j) f = -d;
        else f = j - b[a].offsetHeight - d;
        b[a].style.top = f + "px"
      }
    }
    c.onmouseover = function() {
      if (g) this.className = "onhover";
      var a = this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
      if (a) {
        a.style.visibility = "visible";
        a.style.display = "block";
      }
    };
    c.onmouseout = function() {
      if (g) this.className = "";
      this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
      this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "none"
    }
  }
  for (var a = b.length - 1; a > -1; a--) b[a].style.display = "none"
}








/*navmenu-right*/

var mcVM_options = {
  menuId: "menu-vr",
  alignWithMainMenu: false
};
/* www.menucool.com/vertical/vertical-menu.*/
init_v_menu(mcVM_options);

function init_v_menu(a) {
  if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    start_v_menu(a)
  }, false);
  else window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload", function() {
    start_v_menu(a)
  })
}

function start_v_menu(i) {
  var e = document.getElementById(i.menuId),
    j = e.offsetHeight,
    b = e.getElementsByTagName("ul"),
    g = /msie|MSIE 6/.test(navigator.userAgent);
  if (g)
    for (var h = e.getElementsByTagName("li"), a = 0, l = h.length; a < l; a++) {
      h[a].onmouseover = function() {
        this.className = "onhover"
      };
      h[a].onmouseout = function() {
        this.className = ""
      }
    }
  for (var k = function(a, b) {
      if (a.id == i.menuId) return b;
      else {
        b += a.offsetTop;
        return k(a.parentNode.parentNode, b)
      }
    }, a = 0; a < b.length; a++) {
    var c = b[a].parentNode;
    c.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className += " arrow";
    b[a].style.right = c.offsetWidth + "px";
    b[a].style.top = c.offsetTop + "px";
    if (i.alignWithMainMenu) {
      var d = k(c.parentNode, 0);
      if (b[a].offsetTop + b[a].offsetHeight + d > j) {
        var f;
        if (b[a].offsetHeight > j) f = -d;
        else f = j - b[a].offsetHeight - d;
        b[a].style.top = f + "px"
      }
    }
    c.onmouseover = function() {
      if (g) this.className = "onhover";
      var a = this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
      if (a) {
        a.style.visibility = "visible";
        a.style.display = "block";
      }
    };
    c.onmouseout = function() {
      if (g) this.className = "";
      this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
      this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "none"
    }
  }
  for (var a = b.length - 1; a > -1; a--) b[a].style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
/*nav-menu right*/

#menu-v,
#menu-v ul {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 9;
  margin-top: 135px;
  float: left;
}


/* Top level menu links style
---------------------------------------*/

#menu-v li {
  background: url(bg.gif) repeat-x 0 2px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu-v li a {
  font: normal 17px Gitan Latin;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 39px;
  padding-left: 26px;
  border: none;
}

#menu-v ul li a {
  line-height: 39px;
}

#menu-v li a.arrow:hover {
  background-image: url(../assets/ringsenberg-pfeil-rechts.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 170px 12px;
}


/*Sub level menu items
---------------------------------------*/

#menu-v li ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  /*Sub Menu Items width */
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

#menu-v a.arrow {
  background-image: url(../assets/ringsenberg-pfeil-rechts.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 170px 12px;
}

#menu-v li:hover,
#menu-v li.onhover {
  transition: all .5s;
  background: rgba(198, 156, 109, .2);
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #C69C6D;
}

#menu-v ul li {
  background: none;
}

#menu-v ul li:hover,
#menu-v ul li.onhover {
  background: #FFF;
  background: rgba(198, 156, 109, .2);
  border-right: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #C69C6D;
}

#menu-v li a.top {
  color: white;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#menu-v li a.top:hover {
  color: black;
  background: rgba(226, 205, 182, 1)
}


/*nav-menu right*/

#menu-vr,
#menu-vr ul {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 9;
  margin-top: 135px;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}


/* Top level menu links style
---------------------------------------*/

#menu-vr li {
  background: url(bg.gif) repeat-x 0 2px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu-vr li a {
  font: normal 17px Gitan Latin;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 39px;
  padding-right: 26px;
  border: none;
}

#menu-vr ul li a {
  line-height: 39px;
}

#menu-vr li a.arrow:hover {
  background-image: url(../assets/ringsenberg-menue-pfeil-links.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 30px 12px;
}


/*Sub level menu items
---------------------------------------*/

#menu-vr li ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  /*Sub Menu Items width */
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

#menu-vr a.arrow {
  background-image: url(../assets/ringsenberg-menue-pfeil-links.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 30px 12px;
}

#menu-vr li:hover,
#menu-vr li.onhover {
  transition: all .5s;
  background: rgba(198, 156, 109, .2);
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #C69C6D;
}

#menu-vr ul li {
  background: none;
}

#menu-vr ul li:hover,
#menu-vr ul li.onhover {
  background: #FFF;
  background: rgba(198, 156, 109, .2);
  border-left: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #C69C6D;
}

#menu-vr li a.top {
  color: white;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#menu-vr li a.top:hover {
  color: black;
  background: rgba(226, 205, 182, 1)
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-v">
  <li><a href="#" class="top">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Instrumente</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="vertical-menu#1">Vertical Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="vertical-menu#2">Vertical Menus</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Restauration</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Grafikdesign</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CNC-Fertigung</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<ul id="menu-vr">
  <li><a href="#" class="top">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Instrumente</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="vertical-menu#1">Vertical Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="vertical-menu#2">Vertical Menus</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Restauration</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Grafikdesign</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CNC-Fertigung</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's appearing, but the sub-nav is given a styling of right 200px, so it isn't showing up where it's supposed to be. If you have it give the subnav a styling of left:200px instead, it appears as it's supposed to...which you do have, but it's not taking into effect because you named your function the same name, so both menu's were calling the last start_v_menu function. I changed the names, so it works now.

```js
/*navmenu-left*/

var mcVM_options = {
  menuId: "menu-v",
  alignWithMainMenu: false
};
/* www.menucool.com/vertical/vertical-menu.*/
init_v_menu(mcVM_options);

function init_v_menu(a) {
  if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    start_v_menu(a)
  }, false);
  else window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload", function() {
    start_v_menu(a)
  })
}

function start_v_menu(i) {
  var e = document.getElementById(i.menuId),
    j = e.offsetHeight,
    b = e.getElementsByTagName("ul"),
    g = /msie|MSIE 6/.test(navigator.userAgent);
  if (g)
    for (var h = e.getElementsByTagName("li"), a = 0, l = h.length; a < l; a++) {
      h[a].onmouseover = function() {
        this.className = "onhover"
      };
      h[a].onmouseout = function() {
        this.className = ""
      }
    }
  for (var k = function(a, b) {
      if (a.id == i.menuId) return b;
      else {
        b += a.offsetTop;
        return k(a.parentNode.parentNode, b)
      }
    }, a = 0; a < b.length; a++) {
    var c = b[a].parentNode;
    c.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className += " arrow";
    b[a].style.left = c.offsetWidth + "px";
    b[a].style.top = c.offsetTop + "px";
    if (i.alignWithMainMenu) {
      var d = k(c.parentNode, 0);
      if (b[a].offsetTop + b[a].offsetHeight + d > j) {
        var f;
        if (b[a].offsetHeight > j) f = -d;
        else f = j - b[a].offsetHeight - d;
        b[a].style.top = f + "px"
      }
    }
    c.onmouseover = function() {
      if (g) this.className = "onhover";
      var a = this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
      if (a) {
        a.style.visibility = "visible";
        a.style.display = "block";
      }
    };
    c.onmouseout = function() {
      if (g) this.className = "";
      this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
      this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "none"
    }
  }
  for (var a = b.length - 1; a > -1; a--) b[a].style.display = "none"
}








/*navmenu-right*/

var mcVM_options = {
  menuId: "menu-vr",
  alignWithMainMenu: false
};
/* www.menucool.com/vertical/vertical-menu.*/
init_vr_menu(mcVM_options);

function init_vr_menu(a) {
  if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    start_vr_menu(a)
  }, false);
  else window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload", function() {
    start_vr_menu(a)
  })
}

function start_vr_menu(i) {
  var e = document.getElementById(i.menuId),
    j = e.offsetHeight,
    b = e.getElementsByTagName("ul"),
    g = /msie|MSIE 6/.test(navigator.userAgent);
  if (g)
    for (var h = e.getElementsByTagName("li"), a = 0, l = h.length; a < l; a++) {
      h[a].onmouseover = function() {
        this.className = "onhover"
      };
      h[a].onmouseout = function() {
        this.className = ""
      }
    }
  for (var k = function(a, b) {
      if (a.id == i.menuId) return b;
      else {
        b += a.offsetTop;
        return k(a.parentNode.parentNode, b)
      }
    }, a = 0; a < b.length; a++) {
    var c = b[a].parentNode;
    c.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className += " arrow";
    b[a].style.right = c.offsetWidth + "px";
    b[a].style.top = c.offsetTop + "px";
    if (i.alignWithMainMenu) {
      var d = k(c.parentNode, 0);
      if (b[a].offsetTop + b[a].offsetHeight + d > j) {
        var f;
        if (b[a].offsetHeight > j) f = -d;
        else f = j - b[a].offsetHeight - d;
        b[a].style.top = f + "px"
      }
    }
    c.onmouseover = function() {
      if (g) this.className = "onhover";
      var a = this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
      if (a) {
        a.style.visibility = "visible";
        a.style.display = "block";
      }
    };
    c.onmouseout = function() {
      if (g) this.className = "";
      this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
      this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "none"
    }
  }
  for (var a = b.length - 1; a > -1; a--) b[a].style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
/*nav-menu right*/

#menu-v,
#menu-v ul {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 9;
  margin-top: 135px;
  float: left;
}


/* Top level menu links style
---------------------------------------*/

#menu-v li {
  background: url(bg.gif) repeat-x 0 2px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu-v li a {
  font: normal 17px Gitan Latin;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 39px;
  padding-left: 26px;
  border: none;
}

#menu-v ul li a {
  line-height: 39px;
}

#menu-v li a.arrow:hover {
  background-image: url(../assets/ringsenberg-pfeil-rechts.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 170px 12px;
}


/*Sub level menu items
---------------------------------------*/

#menu-v li ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  /*Sub Menu Items width */
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

#menu-v a.arrow {
  background-image: url(../assets/ringsenberg-pfeil-rechts.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 170px 12px;
}

#menu-v li:hover,
#menu-v li.onhover {
  transition: all .5s;
  background: rgba(198, 156, 109, .2);
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #C69C6D;
}

#menu-v ul li {
  background: none;
}

#menu-v ul li:hover,
#menu-v ul li.onhover {
  background: #FFF;
  background: rgba(198, 156, 109, .2);
  border-right: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #C69C6D;
}

#menu-v li a.top {
  color: white;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#menu-v li a.top:hover {
  color: black;
  background: rgba(226, 205, 182, 1)
}


/*nav-menu right*/

#menu-vr,
#menu-vr ul {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 9;
  margin-top: 135px;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}


/* Top level menu links style
---------------------------------------*/

#menu-vr li {
  background: url(bg.gif) repeat-x 0 2px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu-vr li a {
  font: normal 17px Gitan Latin;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 39px;
  padding-right: 26px;
  border: none;
}

#menu-vr ul li a {
  line-height: 39px;
}

#menu-vr li a.arrow:hover {
  background-image: url(../assets/ringsenberg-menue-pfeil-links.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 30px 12px;
}


/*Sub level menu items
---------------------------------------*/

#menu-vr li ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  /*Sub Menu Items width */
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

#menu-vr a.arrow {
  background-image: url(../assets/ringsenberg-menue-pfeil-links.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 30px 12px;
}

#menu-vr li:hover,
#menu-vr li.onhover {
  transition: all .5s;
  background: rgba(198, 156, 109, .2);
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #C69C6D;
}

#menu-vr ul li {
  background: none;
}

#menu-vr ul li:hover,
#menu-vr ul li.onhover {
  background: #FFF;
  background: rgba(198, 156, 109, .2);
  border-left: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #C69C6D;
}

#menu-vr li a.top {
  color: white;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#menu-vr li a.top:hover {
  color: black;
  background: rgba(226, 205, 182, 1)
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-v">
  <li><a href="#" class="top">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Instrumente</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="vertical-menu#1">Vertical Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="vertical-menu#2">Vertical Menus</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Restauration</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Grafikdesign</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CNC-Fertigung</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<ul id="menu-vr">
  <li><a href="#" class="top">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Instrumente</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="vertical-menu#1">Vertical Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="vertical-menu#2">Vertical Menus</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Restauration</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Grafikdesign</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CNC-Fertigung</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's it! The function name.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your element style on the sub menu.
You set this to:

```
right: 200px
```

I think that you want to set this for the left sub menu to:

```
left: 200px
```